# What does "workflow" mean?

Tags: terminology, workflow

I keep seeing the term "workflow" in relation to post-processing being used here and on other sites. What does it actually mean though?

To me it sounds like it means you do A, then B, then C every time you edit a photo. But that seems strange: no two edits are alike for me and I do find that I do certain things across most photos.

So what does "Workflow" mean?

And can someone provide an example "workflow"?

Comment: Maybe my [Life of A Digital Image](http://www.neocamera.com/article/digital_workflow) can help? It is meant to describe the entire process and encompasses more than post-processing but everything that usually happens to an image.

Comment: I would call what you noted about editing an image the same _every time_ a recipe, template, or preset.

Comment: Related: [What workflow do you follow for managing your photography?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2223/what-workflow-do-you-follow-for-managing-your-photography); [What is the optimal order of post-processing steps?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2318/what-is-the-optimal-order-of-post-processing-steps); [What are the rules for editing a photo?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/20656/what-are-the-rules-for-editing-a-photo/20665#20665)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this particular situation "Workflow" is less *the particular series of edits* you apply to a photo and more **the entire process from capture -> output**.

So things to consider in workflow would be:

1. Capture RAW
2. Import, organize, modify metadata, etc in Lightroom
3. Open to Photoshop for aggressive editing
4. Backup to external storage offsite
5. Export to disk and share to Your Photosharing Site

And this 'workflow' might be different if you shoot JPG, or if you shoot weddings vs portraits, or if you shoot with multiple cameras or if you print, etc

Answer (score 4):

Photography workflow can mean multiple different things, depending on the context and scope.

One could describe the workflow for post-processing, for digital asset management, for image capture, and so forth. Most typically workflow can be described as **the steps taken from the image capture to publishing or archival**.

Since different workflows can be *very* complex, it simply doesn't do it justice here to describe one in short detail. Not only that, but workflows are highly dependent on your circumstances and needs, and thus are very individualized.

Here are some **examples of very well thought out complex photography workflows**:

- [Thomas Hawk Photography Workflow](http://thomashawk.com/2008/06/my-photography-workflow.html)
- [Chase Jarvis Workflow](http://blog.chasejarvis.com/blog/2010/06/workflow-and-backup-for-photo-video/)(One of my favorites)
- [Digital Photography School - Pro Photographer Editing Workflow](http://digital-photography-school.com/pro-photographer-editing-workflow-tips)
- [Photo.net Fine Art Photography Workflow](http://photo.net/learn/digital-photography-workflow/overview/fine-art-photography/)
- [Cambridge In Color Post-Processing Workflow](http://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials/digital-photo-editing-workflow.htm)
- [Scott Kelby's Sports Photography Workflow](http://scottkelby.com/2012/my-sports-photography-workflow-so-far/)

Two texts I will refer you to that can help you to create your own workflow go into much more detail then you can find on any website that I am familiar with:

- [The Digital Photography Workflow Handbook[Gulbins]](http://amzn.com/1933952717)
- [The Dam Book[Krogh]](http://amzn.com/0596523572)

Comment: Ah that's a fair bit of reading for me. I've got something fun to do today! Thanks :)